# Obtener ID mediante jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario con los campos `check_in` y `check_out`.

Deseo que si alguno de los dos está vacío desaparezca el `button` "**Buscar**" y sólo aparezca en caso de que los dos campos están con una fecha.

Tengo incluidas las **librerías** necesarias como **jQuery** y el archivo donde tengo el código **jQuery**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">
<label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>
```

**Código jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $check_in = $(this).attr("check_in");
    $check_out = $(this).attr("check_out");
    if($check_in == "" || $check_out == ""){
            $('#buscar').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para realizar este procedimiento debes primero verificar el valor de cada input, luego dependiendo de sus valores desactivar o activar el boton

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $("#boton").click(function()
    {
      var checkin = $("#checkin").val();
      var checkout = $("#checkout").val();
      if (checkin == "" || checkout == "")
      {
        alert("rellena los campos");
        $("#boton").attr("disabled", "true");
      }
      else
      {
        $("#boton").attr("disabled", "false");
        alert("go");
      }    
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando este considere que hay un cambio en el texto, este valida que uno u el otro no este vacío (debe agregar la función que corrobore que sea una fecha), y elimina el botón de ser necesario.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#check_in").change(function(){
      // if(validarFecha($(this)val())){
       corroborarInputFecha();
      /* }else{
          alert("Debe ingresar una fecha valida");
      */
   });

   $("#check_in").change(function(){
   // if(validarFecha($(this)val())){
       corroborarInputFecha();
      /* }else{
          alert("Debe ingresar una fecha valida");
      */
  });
 });

  function corroborarInputFecha(){
     if($("#check_in").val() == "" || $("#check_out").val() == ""){
         $('#buscar').hide();
     }else{
       $('#buscar').show();
     }
 }
  
  /*
    function validarFecha(fecha){
      //valida fecha
      //return true si es valido
      //return false si no es una fecha
    }
  */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="asd">
    
<label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="xcv" disabled="">
    
<br>
<button id="buscar">Buscar</button>
```

Ejecuta el script y comprueba por favor

Comment: Vale, la solución era más simple: $("#check_in").val(). Con el atributo "val()", obtengo el valor del ID si en $ tengo definido #id.

Comment: Como decía que solo en caso que los dos tuvieran una fecha estuviera el botón buscar y si no este desapareciera, esto hacia aquello. O bien la explicación que diste no fue la mas clara